# how to see scroll panel bottom area when i pressed a button

Tags: gwt, scroll, mgwt

I have a requirement that i want to go to the middle area or bottom area of my scroll panel when I pressed a button ,but not from the scrolling. is it possible to do?..if so how can I reach my goal.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setVerticalScrollPosition()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#setVerticalScrollPosition%28int%29) along with [`getMaximumVerticalScrollPosition()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#getMaximumVerticalScrollPosition%28%29) to go to the end.
For the middle part you have to calculate things by your own getting `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` of the [`getScrollableElement()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#getScrollableElement%28%29).

Comment: but MGWT scrollPanel is not having these kind of methods

Comment: Then poke into [this](http://docs.mgwt.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/latest/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/widget/ScrollPanel.html). I see `getMaxScrollY()` and `scrollTo()` that *may* work as I guess. Never tried, though.